# Updating fields in one web page based upon another?

Tags: javascript, html, web

I have a web page in which you enter some query parameters and it returns the results:

```
Scheme  RespCode    ShortDesc   LongDesc                    Meaning MeaningDescL    MeaningDescS
ABI93   000                     Approved                    A       Approve Apv
ABI93   001                     Honour With Identification  D       Decline Dcn
ABI93   002                     Approved For Partial Amount A       Approve Apv
```

from which I want to correlate the 'RespCode' in another web page with the 'LongDesc'. The second web page is a report that looks like this:

```
 Slot               Label   UserName    Message                RespCode TxnCount    RespTime
2018-03-06 18:00:00 VMGANB  ANBPFD01    VMX.ACCOUNT.INQ        000      2764    0.01237
2018-03-06 18:00:00 VMGANB  ANBPFD01    VMX.ACCOUNT.INQ        118      2   0.01604
2018-03-06 18:00:00 VMGANB  ANBPFD01    VMX.CARDACTIVATION.UPD  000     12  0.01120
2018-03-06 18:00:00 VMGANB  ANBPFD01    VMX.REALTIME.PAY        000     140 0.01729
2018-03-06 18:00:00 VMGANB  ANBPFD01    VMX.REALTIME.PAY        100     17  0.04473
2018-03-06 18:00:00 VMGANB  ANBPFD01    VMX.STATEMENT.INQ       000     67  0.00814
```

and I'd like to see the 3-digit RespCode from the 2nd page replaced with either the LongDesc from the 1st web page.

I'm NOT a web developer, although I have tinkered a bit - could I have both pages open and some JS to parse one page and dynamically update the other? Or should I save both pages, parse the first to build some code to edit the saved 2nd page and then display it?

There is no cgi-bin URL for the report page with the necessary parameters, so I don't think I can trigger the reports from my own web-page and then capture the results and do the necessary substitution.

Edit:
Sorry if I've not explained this very well - I could always copy these 2 pages into Excel and use VLOOKUP to replace the RespCode with the LongDesc, if that makes my intention clearer.

Comment: Could you reformat your data to JSON? It would make a difference when you have to work with it in javascript. You cant really take data from one webpage and inject it in another. You could maybe 20 years ago, but most browsers dosen't allow this now because of cross site scripting.

Comment: @TroelsLenda No unfortunately - I have no control over it. I always wondered what 'cross-site scripting'! I think I'll have to stick to copying and pasting both into Excel and using VLOOKUP. It's just frustrating knowing that the data is there but not being able to do with it what I want.